# Are there any Tor Cloud alternatives?

Tags: bridge, tor-cloud, vps

[Tor Cloud](https://cloud.torproject.org/) makes running a full-time bridge in the cloud fairly easy, and using Amazon's EC2 means there are plenty of locations available at a moderate price. This means though that a lot of Tor-eggs are going into one Amazon-sized basket. Are there any major non-Amazon alternatives?

As diversity is so important for the Tor network it would be great to have similarly simple options for other cloud/VPS providers, without being locked into a single option. How difficult would it be to port the Tor Cloud AMI from Amazon to something like a [Linode StackScript](https://www.linode.com/stackscripts/) or a [DigitalOcean Droplet](https://www.digitalocean.com/one-click-install-applications)?

Failing that, is there anything similar to the Vidalia Bridge Bundle for Linux servers that could easily be installed onto a commodity VPS and left to run?

Answer (score 3):

Setting up your own bridge on a standard Linux system is not very difficult.

Any cloud provider that provides you with an Debian or Ubuntu option would be a good start.  Get the base image, install the [debian packages Tor provides](https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian) and [configure your torrc](https://www.torproject.org/docs/bridges.html.en#RunningABridge) accordingly.  Optionally, add [pluggable transports](https://www.torproject.org/docs/pluggable-transports.html.en).

Voilà.

Maybe this should just be documented better.